Hazard ratio as the odds of dying first
When reading about Hazard ratios on Wikipedia, I found the following cliamclaim under the  Hazard Ratio and Surival item:
$$
HR = \frac{P}{1-P},
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $P$ is meant to be the probability of dying first.
I'm not sure whether that is true, but let me write down what I have done.
Suppose given two random variables $T_1$ and $T_2$, with cumulative distribution functions
$$
F_i(t) = Prob (T_i\leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f_i(t')dt', \qquad i =1,2.
$$
The corresponding survival functions are $S_i(t) = 1 -F_i(t)$, and the Hazard ratio is defined as the quotient
$$
HR = \frac{h_2(t)}{h_1(t)}, \qquad h_i(t) = - \frac{d}{dt} \log S_i(t).
$$
As I interpret ($\ast$), one should have:
$$
HR = \frac{Prob(T_2<T_1)}{1-Prob(T_2<T_1)} .
\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Let's see:
$$
Prob(T_2<T_1) = Prob(T_1-T_2>0) = 1 - Prob(T_1-T_2\leq 0) = \\
=  1 - \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_1(t)f_2(t+t') dt dt',
$$
so we're trying to prove that
$$
HR = \frac{1 - \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_1(t)f_2(t+t') dtdt'}{\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_1(t)f_2(t+t') dtdt'} .
$$
I can get $HR$ on the right-hand side, but I don't see how the integrals are going to cancel out to leave this $HR$ alone.
Plus it'd appear both upstairs and downstairs.
Any ideas on my computations and/or the claim of ($\ast$)?
A somehow related question here.
EDIT
As mentioned in the comments, feel free to assume that the Hazard ratio $HR$ is constant and greater than $1$, so that the event for $T_2$ is more likely to ocurre first.
However, I would like to keep the expression for $h_i(t)$ (or the survival function) as general as possible.
As @Henry says, for the case $h_i(t) = \lambda_i$ constant, $(\dagger)$ gives the desired result $\lambda_2/\lambda_1$. Is it possible to obtain the same in a more general case?

Please correct typos in your question.  For example, you write $$
HR = \frac{Prob(T_2<T_1)}{Prob(T_2<T_1)} .
$$ where the numerator and denominator are the same, and so HR evaluates to $1$ or the indeterminate $\frac 00$.

@DilipSarwate Done

Another typo is $F_i(t) = Prob (T_i\geq t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f_i(t')dt'$ which should have $(T_i\leq t)$

The Wikipedia article you link to is of mixed quality: it starts well enough, saying that the hazard ratio is an instantaneous quantity representing the ratio between two hazard rates for different events $\big($where a hazard rate at time $t$ is $-\frac{S'(t)}{S(t)} = \frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)}\big)$. The section you link to is less well worded, but essentially says that if the hazard ratio is constant over time, then this is equal to the odds (not probability) of the numerator event happening before the denominator event.

One way to demonstrate this might be to assume both hazard rates are constant, i.e. that events are individually and independent exponentially distributed and show the result.  This can be extended to any other continuous distributions with a constant hazard rate by a change of variable which distorts time.

@Henry Oh, yes. I forgot to mention that in my answer, but I'm happy to assume that the hazard ratio $HR$ is constant for all $t$. I will explicitly mention it now. Regarding the last sentence of your second comment, I'm not very familiar with odds, but isn't it exactly what $(\dagger)$ formulates? $HR$ is the odds of the event for $2$ (the numerator) happening before for $1$. Thank you!

Take an example of two events whose time of occurrence are independently exponentially distributed with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ so $F_1(t)=1-e^{-\lambda_1 t}$ and $F_2(t)=1-e^{-\lambda_2 t}$.  Their hazard rates are $\frac{F_1'(t)}{1-F_1(t)} = \lambda_1$  and  $\frac{F_2'(t)}{1-F_2(t)} = \lambda_2$ so constant over time as is their hazard ratio $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}$.  The probability of Event $1$ happening before Event $2$ is $P_{1<2}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ and you can write the hazard ratio as $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}=\frac{P_{1<2}}{1-P_{1<2}}$, which is the odds of Event $1$ happening before Event $2$.
In more general cases, hazard rates and hazard ratios change over time. If we have absolutely continuous independent distributions (so zero probability of both events happening simultaneously) then:

The hazard rates become $\lambda_1(t) = \frac{F_1'(t)}{1-F_1(t)}$ and $\lambda_2(t) = \frac{F_2'(t)}{1-F_2(t)}$.
The probability neither event occurs up to time $t$ and Event $1$ happens by $t+\delta t$ but Event $2$ does not is about $(1-F_2(t+\delta t))\, F_1'(t)\, \delta t =(1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t+\delta t))\, \lambda_1(t)\, \delta t$.
The overall probability Event $1$ happens before Event $2$ is $P_{1<2}=\int_0^\infty (1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t)) \, \lambda_1(t)\, dt$.
Similarly the probability Event $2$ happens before Event $1$ is $P_{2<1}=\int_0^\infty (1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t)) \, \lambda_2(t)\, dt$.
$P_{1<2}+P_{2<1} = 1$.
The instantaneous hazard ratio is $H\!R(t) = \frac{\lambda_1(t)}{\lambda_2(t)}$.
So $\lambda_1(t) = {H\!R(t)}\,{\lambda_2(t)}$ and $P_{1<2}=\int_0^\infty {H\!R(t)}\, (1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t)) \,  \lambda_2(t)\, dt$.

If the hazard ratio were constant over time then $\lambda_1(t) = {H\!R}\,{\lambda_2(t)}$ and so $P_{1<2}={H\!R}\,{P_{2<1}}$, which would give $H\!R = \frac{P_{1<2}}{P_{2<1}} = \frac{P_{1<2}}{1-P_{1<2}}$, the odds of Event $1$ happening before Event $2$.
